# Filter CrystalReport DataSet and binding to the report asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to filter dataset taken to bind report. 
my code is something like this

```
Mohan.Reports.DataSet1 ds1 = DataAccess.TNA_APPROVAL_DATA_FOR_PRINTING_STYLEWISE(DateTime.Now.Date, ddlStyle.SelectedValue);
ds1.Tables[0].Select("StyleNO='" + ddlStyle.SelectedValue + "'");
Reports.CrystalReport1 rp = new Mohan.Reports.CrystalReport1();
//DataRow dt =(DataRow) ds1.Tables[0].Select("StyleNO='" + ddlStyle.SelectedValue + "'");
reportTnaApprovalbyUser.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "StyleNO='" + ddlStyle.SelectedValue + "'");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportTnaApprovalbyUser;
```

But Data is not displaying on report. I think filteration is not working....
Please Help

Comment: Can you debug? Can you see what is coming in reportTnaApprovalbyUser before it is being bound to the report source?

Comment: Thank you but before filteration it is working fine. How should i filter it?